# Highlight the line number in the middle of screen in Vim?

Tags: vim

As it is very convenient to scroll half screen up and down(by using `ctrl-d`), but it is a little hard to estimate which line will disappear after scroll. It will be great if the middle line number can be highlighted, then I can use it as a marker for half screen scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are standard VI commands in *Command Mode*. You may find them helpful:

- `z<Enter>` - Put current line on top of your window
- `z.` - Put current line in the middle of your window
- `z-` - Put current line on the bottom of your window

See `:help z` for more information in VIM. There's a lot of stuff on cursor movements there.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Vim, and implementations of highlights while scrolling are notoriously difficult to implement well (leading to the introduction of the built-in 'cursorline' option to address the top use case).

I frankly don't see the need for that highlight, and I think that once you've learned all the various ways of moving (including commands like `zt` / `zz`, `<C-Y>` / `<C-E>` (which are great for repositioning when you're off a single / few lines only), and plain `j` / `k` with the `'relativenumber'` option), this becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, I used `zz` as workaround and treat the current line as scroll marker, but I'd like to put current line to other position instead of being in the middle.